# python: Arithmetic operation on tuple results in TypeError

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

So I have two different 2-dimensional arrays `words` and `scores`

`words` is a 2-dimensional array of strings
`scores` is a 2-dimensional array of float

I convert them into tuples and perform arithmetic operations on them (I originally pass the tuples to a library that does that, but for simplicity I copied the operation and started testing on it)

**My code**

```
for i in range(0,len(scores)):
    freqs = []
    for word, score in zip(words[i], scores[i]):
        freqs.append((word, score))
        frequencies = [ (word, freq / 20.0) for word, freq in freqs ]
```

when I run this code I get the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-017692219adb> in <module>()
      4     for word, score in zip(words[i], scores[i]):
      5         freqs.append((word, score))
----> 6         frequencies = [ (word, freq / 20.0) for word, freq in freqs ]
      7 
      8         #elements = wc.fit_words(freqs)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: Are you sure `freq` (in your comprehensive list) contains numbers and not strings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`freq` is a string. convert to a float before division.

eg: `float(freq)`

so new code will be `frequencies = [ (word, float(freq) / 20.0) for word, freq in freqs ]`

Answer (score 1):

What the error is basically saying is that you are trying to divide a string by a float so you have to convert the string to float:

```
for i in range(0,len(scores)):
    freqs = []
    for word, score in zip(words[i], scores[i]):
        freqs.append((word, score))
        frequencies = [ (word, float(freq) / 20.0) for word, freq in freqs ]
```